# Passing props from layout to component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

So I'm fairly new to vue and my googlefu may not be good enough, but what I am trying to do is pass props from layout => global component. Is this something that's possible? I'm currently playing around and have a default layout defined as such

layouts/default.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <SiteNav/>
    <nuxt class="nuxt-container"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SiteNav from "../components/SiteNav"

export default {
  test: "corgi",
  components: {
    SiteNav
  }
}
</script>
```

components/SiteNav.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-link to="/sign-in">Click to Sign In</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="/second-page">Click to Second Page</nuxt-link>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    test: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: ""
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$parent.$emit("update:layout", this.test)
  },
  render() {
    return this.$slots.default[0]
  }
}
</script>
```

I've been able to create multiple pages that all uses this global component but I haven't been able to successfully pass props from the layout to the global component. Is there a way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, this is a good one. In nuxt you can actually communicate between non parent/child components and you can use that to communicate to another component in the layout or the layout itself from anything contained in the layout.

In your component you emit whatever you want, so it could be an @click or any method, but in your case you would want to put it inside `mounted()` rather than `created()` otherwise it will cause an error because of the life cycle of events. So:

```
//Component.Vue

<template>
  <div>All your lovely stuff</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
      this.$nuxt.$emit('test', 'blah');
  }
}
</script>
```

Then to listen to the emitted event in your layout you listen for it in created like this.

```
//default.vue

created() {
    this.$nuxt.$on('test', data => {
      console.log(data+' emitted')
      })
    },
```

and your console will log 'blah emitted' when the component is mounted.

You should also turn the listening off like this:

```
beforeDestroy() {
      // $off method will turn off the event listner
      this.$nuxt.$off('test');
  },
```

Comment: Interesting! So the flow of what I want to do is: login-page.vue => sends a piece of information to the component to update. In this example, I see that I can indeed listen to the emitted event in my layout from both the component once it mounts and from login-page where I tested it out. As it is right now, I believe the component won't ever update. Is all I need to do is add the listener to the component and call it from the login-page?

Comment: Excellent. It's a pretty handy feature.

Comment: should `beforeDestroy` be in `default.vue` or `Component.Vue` ?

Comment: @abedelhak.ajbouni, you put beforeDestroy in default.vue. When you turn it on it creates a listener in default.vue, so you are turning it off in the same place you created it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `<SiteNav/>` is in default.vue, you could simply listen to the event like this:

```
<SiteNav @update:layout="updateLayout" />
```

Then you define a `updateLayout` method and its first parameter will be whatever you've emitted from:

```
this.$emit('update:layout', this.test);
```

Note that you must not emit on the $parent object (it makes it harder to track where events come from).

Comment: So to clarify, the updateLayout method should be located inside of the default.vue for setting the prop and this.$emit is put wherever the prop would be changed?

Comment: default.vue contains the `updateLayout` since that is where you use the directive `@update:layout="updateLayout"`. When you use `$emit` you allow other components that use your component to listen to that event using the `@event` syntax

Comment: Right, so I tested that and the method created never seems to be called. "Property or method "updateLayout" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render." I tried calling from a few different areas and the method inside of defaultVue never seems to get triggered.

Comment: you must define your methods in the `methods` key see https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html

Comment: Okay, awesome. The component was able to successfully emit the event and the layout received it. Would you happen to know if a page that was using the layout would be able to pass a prop through? I tried using the same $emit statement in a page and passing in a variable from there but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean there, going from a child to a parent is usually done using the `$emit`. From parent to child you just pass down properties using the `props` key (like `<MyComponent :user="user" />`)