# Dynamically set Vuetify component props based on condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a navbar component made using the v-app-bar vuetify component on my web app. The problem i am experiencing is that i need to set the props of the v-app-bar dynamically based on which page the user is at.

```
 <v-app-bar
  absolute
  color="#43a047"
  dark
  shrink-on-scroll
  prominent
  src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random"
  fade-img-on-scroll
  scroll-target="#scrolling-techniques-5"
  scroll-threshold="500"
>
```

for example the following code above is a basic v-app-bar component with props to enable the app bar to have a image background which fade and decreases in size as the user scrolls down, this is basically what i use on my landing page of the website. so i only want this banner navbar style on the home page only and want a different style when the user is on another page. I have tried making separate navbar components as well as using v-if's inside the component to change the navbar based on the route which as a result causes code duplication (multiple if statements based on routes within navbar component) and is not efficient. For the website I am building (interactive large scale website with different types of user accounts), it would be very much easier if i could set the v-app-bar Vuetify props dynamically from the page making using of the v-app-bar rather than making separate navbar components with these changes for each page.

Comment: Can you explain on detail what kind of style you want it be? For simple style like color, the easiest way is dynamically bind the class into it

Answer (score -1):

I will assume you are using the v-app-bar in your layout and therefore as you say, accessing the route with `this.$route` would entail a lot of ifs or a large switch statement and is not so performant.

As each route in nuxt is defined by the page file it is written in you can use that to pass details to the layout which can then use those as props in the v-app-bar. To do that you can use the event bus. I have a previous answer detailing it's use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199158/passing-props-from-layout-to-component/55202378#55202378) but i can outline how to apply it here.

It would appear you want to pass such props as color, src, scroll-target etc to tailor the nav bar. From your page you can pass these props like so:

```
//index.vue -- or any route 

export default {
  mounted() {
      let props = {
        color: '#43a047',
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random',
        scroll-target: '#scrolling-techniques-5',
        scroll-threshold: 500
      }
      this.$nuxt.$emit('appBarProps', props);
  }
}
```

Then in your layout listen for the event bus like this:

```
//default.vue

created() {
    this.$nuxt.$on('appBarProps', p => {
      this.appBarProps = p;
      })
    },

data() {
    return {
      appBarProps: {}
    } 
}

beforeDestroy() {
    this.$nuxt.$off('appBarProps');
},
```

and use the appBarProps object in your v-app-bar